# How do I replace certain words in a text file with '*'?

Tags: string, matlab, io

Hello I have a text file that has

```
  Treadstone project

  Jason Bourne is to neutralize Wombosi.

  Nicky Parsons is the technician on the job

  Bourne has shown interest in Marie Kreutz

  Do not leak information about Blackbriar.
```

I have a cell array with

```
words = {'treadstone','bourne','wombosi','parsons','blackbriar'}
```

I am suppose to get this

```
********** project

Jason ****** is to neutralize *******.

Nicky ******* is the technician on the job

****** has shown interest in Marie Kreutz

Do not leak information about **********.
```

But my code is printing this

```
********** project

Jason ****** is to neutralize Wombosi

Jason bourne is to neutralize *******.

Nicky ******* is the technician on the job

****** has shown interest in Marie Kreutz

Do not leak information about **********.
```

Here is my code:

```
while ischar(line)
if strcmp(line, '')
    fprintf(output, line);
    line = fgetl(fh);
end
[T N] = size(words);
for i = 1:N
    mat = words{i}; %extreact the first word to comapre it to the text file
    if strfind(lower(line), mat)
        t = mat; 
        t(1:end) = '*'; %replace the word with *
        ht = strfind(lower(line), mat); %find its location 
        hat = lower(line(ht));
        line(ht) = hat; %replace the word with lower case
        lalu = strrep(line, mat, t); 

        fprintf(output, '%s\n', lalu);
    else 
        hat = 0;
    end


end

line = fgetl(fh);
end
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your taste of movies is awesome.  All joking aside, I'll write an answer.

Comment: Question.  Are you purposely bold facing your text, or are those `*` characters part of the original text?  It's very confusing.

Comment: I am just bold facing my text so that it wold be easy to read. I couldn't bold face some of the them like  ********** project.

Comment: OK... so please check my edits to your post if I got them right.

Comment: Yup that is what it is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for the most part.  However, if you have more than one matching string in one sentence, you are not updating that sentence properly to block out each word.  You are only blocking the words individually and are not updating all of the words in the one string.  You'll also need to put that `fprintf` statement outside of the inner loop when you're done.  By putting the `fprintf` statement inside the `for` loop, you would write the string when finding a particular string within a sentence was successful.  You only want to write the string to text once you check for **all** words - that's why your text file has certain sentences repeated.  This is because you have more than one matching string in the sentence.

As such, do something like this:

```
while ischar(line)
if strcmp(line, '')
    fprintf(output, line);
    line = fgetl(fh);
end
[T N] = size(words);
for i = 1:N
    mat = lower(words{i}); %extreact the first word to comapre it to the text file
                           % Also cast to lower to ensure case-sensitive
    if strfind(lower(line), mat)
        t = mat; 
        t(1:end) = '*'; %replace the word with *
        ht = strfind(lower(line), mat); %find its location 
        hat = lower(line(ht));
        line(ht) = hat; %replace the word with lower case
        line = strrep(line, mat, t);   %// UPDATE STRING HERE
    else 
        hat = 0;
    end           
end

fprintf(output, '%s\n', line); %// Print out string once all replacing is done

line = fgetl(fh);
end
```

---

I had to do some set up before getting your code to work.  I placed your text in a file called `bourne.txt`, then did this before I ran the code:

```
fh = fopen('bourne.txt', 'r');
line = fgetl(fh);
words = {'treadstone','bourne','wombosi','parsons','blackbriar'};
output = fopen('output.txt', 'w');
```

I wrote the text to `output.txt`.  When I used the above code and run the corrected code, I got:

```
 ********** project
 Jason ****** is to neutralize *******.
 Nicky ******* is the technician on the job
 ****** has shown interest in Marie Kreutz
 Do not leak information about **********.
```

Now that we have successfully classified your text file, Jason Bourne would be proud:

[image]

Comment: Haha That's a nice one... Thank you very much.